# Excel AND and NOT

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, syntax

Please can you help:

I have an Excel query.
I use IF AND and NOT.
When I write 3 AND statements it works.
When I write 1 AND and 2 NOT statements it works too.
When I write 2 AND and 1 NOT this does not work - This is the last 4 lines of the IF statement below.

How do you create an AND and NOT statement in Excel: I want to show two AND and 1 NOT. I have done this current by: AND( statement 1 and statement 2, NOT( statement 3)) - but this does not work.

This image is not the calculation, it just shows I need to write 8 lots of IF statements.

[image]

```
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="NO ASSISTANT",Overview!$D$5="ALL",Overview!$D$6="ALL")),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="ASSISTANT",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$5="ALL",Overview!$D$6="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="NO ASSISTANT",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$5="ALL",Overview!$D$6="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="ASSISTANT",Overview!$D$5="ALL",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$6="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="NO ASSISTANT",Overview!$D$5="ALL",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$6="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="ASSISTANT",Overview!$D$6="ALL",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$5="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x),
IF((AND(Overview!$D$8="NO ASSISTANT",Overview!$D$6="ALL",NOT(AND(Overview!$D$5="ALL")))),SUMIFS(x)))))))))
```

Comment: Instead of this super long formula, I think you rather want to explain what it is you are trying and what your input and desired results are. Your current attempt is in place but there may just be a better way to achieve what it is you are after.

Comment: Thanks.  How do you create an AND and NOT statement in Excel: I want to show two AND and 1 NOT.  I have done this current by: AND( statement 1 and statement 2, NOT( statement 3)) - but this does not work.

Comment: This clearly shows that the result of two "x" is "works" and any one "x" means "not working". Is thast really what you mean?

Comment: Provide your example as text to save people having to type on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume the "x" means available based on the results you show, so this works:

[image]

Based on the comment that seems to state a different case to that shown in the OP's image then this version works:

[image]

Comment: X means this will be the NOT, part of the statement.  I have the X column linked to a dropdown list.  If X means it is not connected to the dropdown. If I can workout the AND and NOT then the rest will be fine.  Thanks

Comment: Well, the image you shows gives two "x" as works... But all you need to do is change the 2 to 0.